# Branching then tagging with the Release plugin

Tags: maven, release

I'm learning how to use the Maven Release Plugin and I have a question with the process of tagging/branching. I'm working on a project called "test" version 1.0-SNAPSHOT. I'm ready for the release. I can prepare the release and perform the release but Maven only creates a tag and I also want a branch for maintenance (bug fixes). I know that there is a possibility to branch with the Release plugin, but the branch goal doesn't create a tag also. I understand that when you want to branch, you don't want to tag. But, generally when you create a tag from the trunk (because release 1.0 in this case), you would want to branch for future maintenance.

Is there a way to configure the prepare/perform goal(s) to also branch the project before or after creating the tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK no. But simply copy the /tag/test-root-1.0 to /branches/test-root-1.0. Then you need to update the versions in the pom. For this you can simply use the "mvn versions:set" goal and set the version to "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT". You are probably up to scripting these two commands in bash script if you need to make it look as one :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider integrating the `maven-scm-plugin` into the mix.  Either `scm:tag` or `scm:branch` before or after your `release` goals should do the trick.